# C++11 for_each and lambdas optimization

Tags: c++, lambda, g++, c++11

I'm testing the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   std::vector<int> v(10000000);
   clock_t then = clock();
   if(argc <= 1)
      std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int& it){ it = 10098; });
   else
      for(auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) *it = 98775;
   std::cout << clock() - then << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling it with g++ 4.6, without any optimization flags and here is what I get:

```
[javadyan@myhost experiments]$ ./a.out 
260000
[javadyan@myhost experiments]$ ./a.out aaa
330000
[javadyan@myhost experiments]$
```

Using -O1 optimization yields the following (unsurprising) results:

```
[javadyan@myhost experiments]$ ./a.out 
20000
[javadyan@myhost experiments]$ ./a.out aaa
20000
```

I'm running Linux 3.0 on a dualcore 2Ghz laptop, if that matters.

What I'm wondering is how in a program compiled without any optimizations a call to for_each with a lambda function could eat less clocks than a plain for loop? Shouldn't there be even a slight overhead from calling the anonymous function? Is there any documentation on how code like this

```
 std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int& it){ it = 10098; });
```

is handled by g++? What is the behavior of other popular compilers in this case?

**UPDATE**

I didn't consider the fact that `it` in the second expression gets compared to `v.end()` on every iteration. With that fixed, the for loop eats less clocks than for_each. However, I'm still curious about how the compiler optimizes the for_each when -O1 flag is used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a first glance, I can say at least that those expressions are not equivalent. Try with this instead:

```
  for(auto it = v.begin(), end = v.end(); it != end; ++it) *it = 98775;
```

Also, since the exact type of the lambda is passed to `for_each`, there are pretty good chances that the compiler will inline it resulting in code no different than the for loop. Note that there are no virtual calls involved in anonymous functions. The compiler will do something like this:

```
class __lambda_function_123
{
public:
    void operator()(int& it) const{ it = 10098; }
};

std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), __lambda_function_123());
```

which in addition to inlining, will result in the very same code than the for loop (with my modification included).

Comment: Tried it. Case closed :) `[javadyan@myhost experiments]$ ./a.out 
260000
[javadyan@myhost experiments]$ ./a.out aaa
180000`

Comment: @GrigoryJavadyan: Out of curiosity, what are results with optimisation enabled? :)

Comment: Still would like to hear an explanation of how g++ manages to significantly reduce the number of cycles for the first expression (using a lambda) when -O1 is used. I reckon the anonymous function gets inlined or something?

Comment: @VladLazarenko I mentioned it with in the original post, 20000 clocks in both cases with -O1 (-O3 yields the same results actually)

Comment: @GrigoryJavadyan: yeah, I see. BTW, `clock ()` is an epic fail when it comes to measuring performance. Its precision is off by thousands in return. Try using high-precision wall clock, like `clock_gettime ()` with MONOTONIC flags..

Comment: @Grigory Make sure that the code is executed at all when optimising. You are not using the result. If I were the C++ compiler, I would just elide the whole code (except for the output of some arbitrary time). Your current benchmark code is flawed for this reason. Do change it to have a side-effect that prevents the compiler from eliding any code.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, even after making the "end = v.end(), i != end" optimization, your for_each & lambda case still runs faster in Visual Studio 2010 in debug mode.

One optimization which makes it faster in VS2010 is the fact that the meta template machinery can detect the use of a vector iterator and switch to using raw pointers to integers for begin/end which eliminates alot of validation checks during debug mode for both the operator ++, operator *, and operator !=.